# Are Cal Kit (SOLT) definitions unique by serial number?

Tags: calibration, vna

I have an E5071B Network Analyzer and 85033E cal kit.
One of the standards is broken now and needs to be replaced. This is the Male OPEN standard (Part number 85033-60018).

Question: 
Will the definition files (that come on the floppy disk, and are now installed in my VNA) still be valid after I replace the broken OPEN standard? Basically, are the definition files specific to each individual kit per serial number or is it just one set of definition files that works for all 85033E kits?

Comment: Try a call to HP/Agilent/Keysight technical support in the USA. I had this exact instrument and an older kit. I called them and was put straight through to a PhD VNA application engineer who knew all the detail, he mailed me a scan of an ancient paper manual with all the constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be either way.

Some kits are characterized individually, some only by model number.

A high priced Keysight kit is probably characterized individually, but you could check with Keysight to be sure. If it is individually characterized, they should provide new characterization data with the replacement standard.

However, I was told by one cal kit vendor (not Keysight) that even though they charge more for an individually characterized kit, they actually think their EM modelling is more accurate than the equipment and references they use to do the cal kit characterization, so the generic characterization data provided with the lower-cost kits is actually better than the measurement-derived data provided with the individually characterized kits.

So your mileage may vary.